# Sharepoint 2013 version history for anonymous users

Tags: 2013, permissions, access, version-history

i have Sharepoint 2013 site with anonymous access enabled. I have custom list with versioning enabled.

Can anyone tell me best way to enable "Version History" access (view permissions) for anonymous users.

Comment: You want that anonymous users should be able to view versIon history?

Comment: What access level do anonymous users have?

Comment: Yes, I want to anonymous users should be able to view version history.
Anonymous users have access level "Entire web site"

Answer (score 0):

If the permission of the anonymous access is “Entire web site”, the anonymous user can view version history and restore the previous version.

Comment: Im not sure. Login is required anytime when I try it as anonymous.

Comment: you could enable anonymous access in IE.

Comment: Can you describe little more, how can i do it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: you could open IE->internet options->security option->custom level->in the settings, find "user authentication"->select anonymous logon.

Comment: Not working. You can try it :) http://eudeska.justice.cz/Lists/EUD/AllItems.aspx